# Chrome devtools returns null when element is clearly on page

Tags: web-scraping, rust

I try to implement a webscraper.

I thought the issue was my rust code for the longest time but as the title suggests it seems to be the query selector I am trying to use to locate the element.
I am trying to crall [this](https://pokerdb.thehendonmob.com/player.php?a=r&n=182652) page and extract the href on the twitter follow button.

When using `$$("#follow-button")` in chrome devTools I get a null response until the element is inspected then the query returns the correct thing. Could anyone please shed some light on why this element doesn't seem to exist until inspected? I can provide links to rust code if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is in an iframe. You have to select the Iframes src, and request for it's document, then you can select any of its children.